# CAMLquery nested AND

Tags: sharepoint-addin, caml-query

I want to get all the items from my list, like this (A&B) AND (C&D), but my CAMLquery doesn't seem to work, here is what I've tried so far:

`var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(
"<View>" +
"<Query>" +
"<Where>" +
"<And>" +
"<And>" +
"<Eq><FieldRef Name='Prioritet'/><Value Type='Text'>A</Value></Eq>" +
"<Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>B</Value></Eq>" +
"</And>" +
"<And>" +
"<Eq><FieldRef Name='Prioritet'/><Value Type='Text'>C</Value></Eq>" +
"<Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>D</Value></Eq>" +
"</And>" +
"</And>" +
"</Where>" +
"</Query>" +
"</View>");`

Comment: This won't work since this CAML query is checking if the column `Prioritet` and `Status` have 2 different values in an item i.e. it's checking if `Prioritet` has values A and C for the same item which is impossible. I'd suggest reformulating your query.

Comment: as say @uberz91, this should be Or instead an AND
For example:
<Or><And></And><And></And></Or>

Answer (score -1):

the syntax is each `< and>` statement content 2 queries.

section `<and>` is one query in another `<and>` statement

change the query to:

```
"<View>" +
  "<Query>" +
    "<Where>" +
        "<And>" +
            "<And>" +
                "<And>" + <------first
                    "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Prioritet'/><Value Type='Text'>A</Value></Eq>" + <----- 1
                    "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>B</Value></Eq>" + <------2
                "</And>" +
                "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Prioritet'/><Value Type='Text'>C</Value></Eq>" + <----- second
            "</And>" +
            "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>D</Value></Eq>" +
        "</And>" +
    "</Where>" +
  "</Query>" +
"</View>"
```

Comment: The query syntax is correct. Main `<And>` contains two child `<And>` tags, and both child tags contain two `<Eq>` tags. Only problem is in contradictory conditions which your answer doesn't fix.